# hide checkbox on particular date using moment and angular js

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I want to hide a checkbox on a certain date for example 17 Nov using AngularJS and MomentJS.
I used a function

```
$scope.today = moment('2017-11-17').toDate();
$scope.checkNov = function(value) {
  if (moment().diff(value, 'day') == 0 && moment().diff(value, 'month') == 0 && moment().diff(value, 'year') == 0) return true;
}
```

and called it on div for checkbox

```
<div ng-hide="checkNov(today)">
<input type="checkbox"></div>
```

the function is returning `value=true` that will give `ng-hide="true"` then it should hide. But it is still visible.

Also how to check for exact date comparision using Moment.JS? Because when I checked using `console.log` it is working for 18 nov as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for the exact date comparison
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/

Comment: if (moment().isSame(moment('2017-11-17'), 'day'))
                return true;
            else
                return false  this is working but how to use format to work with different timezone. Thank you